# PHPExcel fill the accents as false

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem with PHPExcel library 1.7.9 creating a xlsx.

Im using fromArray method to fill a MySQL table into an xlsx, when i try to fill any cell with accents, the cell is filled as "FALSE".

[image]

This is my code:

```
$query="SELECT 
    Caso,
    Etq_Amarilla,
    Tipo,
    Etiqueta,
    'EC Sociedad',
    ProveedorEscalado,
    Proveedor_de_Mantenimiento,
    organizativo,
    OficinaPeople,
    centro,
    sociedad,
    Tipo_Disp,
    Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion,
    Fecha_y_hora_de_cierre,
    domicilio,
    jcentro04,
    analitico,
    DTDT
from CdM_Diario where Dia='5'";

$datos=$mysqli->query($query);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(4);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cabecera,NULL,"A1");
$cont=2;
while($fila=$datos->fetch_assoc())
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($fila,"pepe","A".$cont."");
    $cont++;
}
$cont=2;
```

**Solved with:**

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

**Thanks to Mark Baker**

Comment: Before putting the data try a var_dump of the vars

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fill any cell with accents"? Are you talking about strings with accented characters?

Comment: Yes, words like "acción"

Comment: PHPExcel expects UTF-8: if the data from your database isn't utf-8, then you will need to convert it to utf-8 before storing it in the PHPExcel object

Comment: My DB is utf8_general_ci :\

Comment: I have made the var_dump and also its ok returning strings as i need

Comment: In that case, if you __guarantee__ that the value is a string, and that it is indeed utf-8, then are you using any value binder other than the default one? PHPExcel may change data being stored in a cell based on a value binder

Comment: However, note that `utf8_general_ci` is a database __collation__, not a database __charset__

Comment: The charset is utf8 also.

Comment: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Just glad its working for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it's quite old, but I came across the same today and `utf8_encode($row['field'])` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

PHPExcel works with UTF-8 charset, you need to use UTF-8 data or convert it before setting it to your object.

```
 $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

should do the trick.

credit to @Mark Baker